# PHP decimal point sum is possible

Tags: php, floating-point, sum, decimal

I am trying to sum this in php:

```
.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1
```

It should give me result '1' but it is giving me answer '0.9999'

Here is my code

```php
<?php

class Num
{
    public static function fsum(...$num)
    {
        $s = 0;
        foreach ($num as $n) {
            $s = sprintf('%.f', $s) + sprintf('%.f', $n);
        }
        return sprintf('%.f', $s);
    }
}

var_dump(Num::fsum(.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1));
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: Why 0.999 ? `10 * 0.1 = 1`

Comment: @help-info.de look here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum
What my question floating point sum, so it should be 100% accurate result rather then round of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works too (you have 10 inputs so 0.1*10=1). But do mathematical operations on string is bad idea. Its better use number and format the number on output.

```
class Num
{
    public static function fsum(...$num)
    {

        $s = 0;
        foreach ($num as $n) {
            $s = $s + (float) $n;
        }
        return sprintf('%.f', $s);
    }
}

var_dump(Num::fsum(.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1));
```

Comment: No it return `1.000000` which is not true

Comment: The result should be `1.00`. @daremachine is correct.

Comment: @Andrei look here https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum
Look to first example

Comment: what have python in common with php?

Comment: It has nothing to do with php but rather the example he follows. The lib he's basing his answer on does not use full precision math on arbitrary operations.

Comment: @MuhamamdUmerFarooq this is not a python issue

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [`bcmath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library for precise math operations. While this isn't the case here, it would be still advised.

```
class Num
{
    public static function fsum(...$num)
    {
        $s = 0;
        foreach ($num as $n) {
            $s = bcadd($s, $n, 2); // precision of 2, set to your own needs
        }
        return $s;
    }
}

var_dump(Num::fsum(.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1));
```

Comment: This still is not producing write result
My question is about accurate results as in python look here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum
look to first example

Comment: The example you provide does not take into account float point precision. And it should not be used for arbitrary precision math. You'd need [full precision](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/).